# Módulo URL Rewrite 2 de IIS detecta mal el Sistema Operativo

Tags: iis

Mi problema es que cuando intento instalar el Módulo URL Rewrite 2 de IIS (Internet Information Server) detecta mal el Sistema Operativo, saliendo el siguiente mensaje:

> Módulo URL Rewrite 2 de IIS no se puede instalar en Vista Home

Obviamente mi sistema operativo es Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64. He realizado la instalación en otro sistema operativo de las mismas características y me funciona. Básicamente tienen la misma configuración en el IIS pero sigue sin funcionar.

Adjunto la imagen para mayor claridad.

[image: Modulo URL Rewrite 2 de IIS]